# Text storage for mysql

Tags: mysql, datatypes, varchar

So I want to create a command like first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ... however I want the database to hold more characters like a text storage type. How would I set up the command for the text type?

Comment: Use text instead of varchar?

Comment: would it be first_name TEXT NOT NULL, ? When I enter that when creating a table, a syntax error comes up. My question was quite vague but I'm just asking for the format for a text command.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE test (first_name text NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: @Dave why posting a comment instead of an ANSWER?

Comment: Why would it be different from any other type? The ENGINE=InnoDB is the default, you should also not be using utf8, but utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  first_name text
);
```

The `ENGINE` is InnoDB by default. Your `default-character-set` should be set to `utf8mb4` changing that to the older `utf8` is a very bad. Just leave well enough alone.

BTW, I fully agree with Rick James, you really don't want `text` here. The MySQL best practices would be something like `varchar(255)` which stores the column in-line. There are [storage implications of using `text`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) on MySQL (though not in PostgreSQL). From [the docs,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

> Each `BLOB` or `TEXT` value is represented internally by a separately allocated object. This is in contrast to all other data types, for which storage is allocated once per column when the table is opened.

They're also a byte bigger than `varchar(255)`

For more information see

- [*What is the difference between MySQL `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` data types?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/386/2639)

Comment: If `first_name` is what it says, `TEXT` is overkill.  How about `VARCHAR(225)`?  Guiness says that "Barnaby Marmaduke Aloysius Benjy Cobweb Dartagnan Egbert Felix Gaspar Humbert Ignatius Jayden Kasper Leroy Maximilian Neddy Obiajulu Pepin Quilliam Rosencrantz Sexton Teddy Upwood Vivatma Wayland Xylon Yardley Zachary Usansky" is the longest first_name.

Comment: @RickJames updated.. But maybe he needs room for future absurdity? =)

Comment: `BLOB` and `TEXT` are not always stored separately; it depends on row format and data length.  Still, they have some optimization deficiencies, plus a prohibition of using in an `INDEX`.  (I don't count index prefixing as being useful.)

Comment: @RickJames that's only true for MyISAM. InnoDB **always** stores blobs and text out-of-line, afaik.

Comment: @RickJames could be worng though seems to be some disagreement over it, have at it https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/210408/2639

Comment: @RickJames sorry for the late response but the first_name VARCHAR command was fine. For my project I am creating a form that users can write in, which would require more than 255 characters, which is why I want to use TEXT. When I do use TEXT (x) tho it returns a syntax error.

Comment: `When I do use TEXT (x)` what do you mean, and what is `(x)`? Just use `TEXT`

Comment: x is the number of bits so in my case I want to be able to store 65,535 bits

Comment: and I havent tried just using TEXT so I will try it out rn

Comment: @wonderhead - `TEXT`, by definition can hold _up to_ 64K bytes.  There is no need for `(x)`.  `MEDIUMTEXT` can hold up to 16MB.