# In what cases are BLOB and TEXT stored in-line on InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, storage, database-internals, blob

I've googled this and can't find it, you can see [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) mention it here.

> ... `BLOB` and `TEXT` are not always stored separately

The answer on [*What is the difference between MySQL VARCHAR and TEXT data types?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/418/2639) says,

> InnoDB is similar for `VARCHAR`, but stores the complete `TEXT` field outside of the record.

That's not the only massively upvote answer with this stance. [From StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2023513/124486) you can find an answer with **754 upvotes** that says it quite clearly,

> `TEXT` and `BLOB` is stored off the table with the table just having a pointer to the location of the actual storage.
>
> `VARCHAR` is stored inline with the table. `VARCHAR` is faster when the size is reasonable, the tradeoff of which would be faster depends upon your data and your hardware, you'd want to benchmark a realworld scenario with your data.

The [comment here links to a post on a mailing list that says](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/386/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-varchar-and-text-data-types/418#comment4841_418)

> MyISAM puts `TEXT` and `BLOB` 'inline'. If you are searching a table (range scan / table scan), you are 'stepping over those cow paddies' -- costly for disk I/O. That is, the existence of the inline blob hurts performance in this case.
>
> InnoDB puts only 767 bytes of a `TEXT` or `BLOB` inline, the rest goes into some other block. This is a compromise that sometimes helps, sometimes hurts performance.

I've seen other posts that talk about storing text and blobs in-line if they're under some limit? What is the limit? When, if ever, does InnoDB store blobs and texts in line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For InnoDB the rule goes like this:

- A record can not be fragmented.
- At least two records must fit in a page.
- If a record size is less than ~7k, all field values are stored in-page.
- If the record size is more than ~7k the first 768 (`COMPACT` format) or 20 bytes (`DYNAMIC` format) are stored in-page. The remaining part is stored off-page.

How to verify that.

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


mysql> insert into t1(name) select repeat('a', 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into t1(name) select repeat('a', 8000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Then parse the `t1.ibd` with [stream_parser](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb).

```
stream_parser -f t1.ibd
```

Check content of the PRIMARY index page:

```
# hexdump -C pages-t1.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0000000000000046.page
00000000  97 e5 5e 36 00 00 00 03  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |..^6............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 27 b9 44  45 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.....'.DE.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 18 00 02  1f f3 80 04 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 a2 00 02 00 01 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 2e 00 00 00 18 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 02 00 f2 00 00 00 18  00 00 00 02 00 32 01 00  |.............2..|
00000060  02 00 1c 69 6e 66 69 6d  75 6d 00 03 00 0b 00 00  |...infimum......|
00000070  73 75 70 72 65 6d 75 6d  0a 00 00 00 10 00 23 80  |supremum......#.|
00000080  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 05  10 ae 00 00 01 22 01 10  |............."..|
00000090  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  61 61 40 9f 00 00 00 18  |aaaaaaaaaa@.....| <- this is the first record
000000a0  ff ce 80 00 00 02 00 00  00 00 05 11 af 00 00 01  |................|
000000b0  23 01 10 61 61 61 61 61  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  |#..aaaaaaaaaaaaa| <- this is the beginning of the second record
000000c0  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  |aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|
* <- The star means identical strings are omitted, -v will show full output.
00001ff0  61 61 61 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |aaa.............|
00002000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00003ff0  00 00 00 00 00 70 00 63  97 e5 5e 36 00 27 b9 44  |.....p.c..^6.'.D|
00004000  97 e5 5e 36 00 00 00 03  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |..^6............|
00004010  00 00 00 00 00 27 b9 44  45 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.....'.DE.......|
00004020  00 00 00 00 00 18 00 02  1f f3 80 04 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004030  00 a2 00 02 00 01 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 2e 00 00 00 18 00 00  |................|
00004050  00 02 00 f2 00 00 00 18  00 00 00 02 00 32 01 00  |.............2..|
00004060  02 00 1c 69 6e 66 69 6d  75 6d 00 03 00 0b 00 00  |...infimum......|
00004070  73 75 70 72 65 6d 75 6d  0a 00 00 00 10 00 23 80  |supremum......#.|
00004080  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 05  10 ae 00 00 01 22 01 10  |............."..|
00004090  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  61 61 40 9f 00 00 00 18  |aaaaaaaaaa@.....|
000040a0  ff ce 80 00 00 02 00 00  00 00 05 11 af 00 00 01  |................|
000040b0  23 01 10 61 61 61 61 61  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  |#..aaaaaaaaaaaaa|
000040c0  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61  |aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|
*
00005ff0  61 61 61 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |aaa.............|
00006000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00007ff0  00 00 00 00 00 70 00 63  97 e5 5e 36 00 27 b9 44  |.....p.c..^6.'.D|
00008000
```

This is for `COMPACT` format. For `DYNAMIC` (except `COMPRESSED`) the procedure is same.

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that there are 4 "row formats".  A main difference between then has to do with how wide columns are handled.

The reference points to an Answer written early in 2010, a few months before `DYNAMIC` and `COMPRESSED` were introduced in the "InnoDB plugin".

*So, I claim that that other Q&A is out of date!*  That is the 754 Upvotes are no longer valid.

Here are some 'current' manual references:

(emphasis mine)

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format-overview.html :

> Columns such as BLOB **and VARCHAR** that are too long to fit on a B-tree page are stored on separately allocated disk pages called overflow pages.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html :

> When a table is created with **ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED**, InnoDB can store long variable-length column values (for VARCHAR, VARBINARY, and BLOB and TEXT types) **fully off-page**, with the clustered index record containing only a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page.
>
> [DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED] When the row is too long, InnoDB chooses the longest columns for off-page storage until the clustered index record fits on the B-tree page. TEXT and BLOB columns that are **less than or equal to 40 bytes are always stored in-line**.
>
> The **DYNAMIC** format is based on the idea that if a portion of a long data value is stored off-page, it is usually most efficient to store all of the value off-page. With DYNAMIC format, **shorter columns are likely to remain in the B-tree node**, minimizing the number of overflow pages needed for any given row.
>
> The **COMPRESSED** row format uses similar internal details for off-page storage as the DYNAMIC row format

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-physical-record.html (even a big `CHAR` may be treated like `TEXT`):

> InnoDB [all formats?] encodes fixed-length fields greater than or equal to 768 bytes in length as variable-length fields, which can be stored off-page. For example, a **CHAR(255)** column can exceed 768 bytes if the maximum byte length of the character set is greater than 3, as it is with utf8mb4.
>
> ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC and ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED handle CHAR storage in the same way as ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT.

(The links are for 5.6, but I think the text applies at least to newer versions.)

I see nothing specific that says that `VARCHAR(...)` and `*TEXT` are handled differently.

Comment: So then the traditional wisdom that TEXT is out of line, or simply *more* out-of-line is just a fabrication with no more footing in modern versions?

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Things have changed over time.  With good reason.  Having `TEXT` _always_ off-record is "less often" the better choice than having it in-line when it is short.  Etc.  Still, I see no reason to ever use `TINYTEXT` instead of `VARCHAR(255)`.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Thanks for raising the question; it needed revisiting.  There are a small number of other "old wives' tales" than need revisiting.  Maybe the "myisam is faster" myth is finally put to rest.